# Receive extra null byte when using serial port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I'm writing a program for serial port data transmission on Linux, but find that every time the sender opens the port, the receiver gets an extra null byte `'\x00'`.

Here's the code of sender:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int fd_com_ = open("/dev/ttyAM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

  struct termios attrs_;
  attrs_.c_iflag = IGNBRK;
  attrs_.c_oflag = 0;
  attrs_.c_cflag = (CLOCAL | CREAD);
  attrs_.c_cflag |= CS8;
  attrs_.c_lflag = 0;
  attrs_.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
  attrs_.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  cfsetspeed(&attrs_, B115200);

  tcsetattr(fd_com_, TCSANOW, &attrs_);

  const char *s = "abcd";
  write(fd_com_, s, 4);
  sleep(1);
  write(fd_com_, s, 4);
  sleep(1);
  close(fd_com_);

  fd_com_ = open("/dev/ttyAM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
  write(fd_com_, s, 4);

  return 0;
}
```

The receiver has the same configuration, but receives `"\x00abcdabcd\x00abcd"`. How to fix this problem so the receiver could get `"abcdabcdabcd"`?

---

**Update:**

The code of receiver:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int fd_com_ = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

  struct termios attrs_;
  attrs_.c_iflag = IGNBRK;
  attrs_.c_oflag = 0;
  attrs_.c_cflag = (CLOCAL | CREAD);
  attrs_.c_cflag |= CS8;
  attrs_.c_lflag = 0;
  attrs_.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
  attrs_.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  cfsetspeed(&attrs_, B115200);

  tcsetattr(fd_com_, TCSANOW, &attrs_);

  char buf[100];
  ssize_t sz;
  while(1) {
    sz = read(fd_com_, buf, 100);
    if (sz > 0) {
      for (ssize_t i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        printf("%02hhx\n", buf[i]);
      }
    }
    sleep(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you open and close the port only, do you receive the null byte too? Can you post the receiver code?

Comment: @iharob Yes, after commenting the last `write` the receiver still gets a null byte. I have posted the code of receiver.

Comment: Can you describe the serial port setup, what is connected where.

Comment: @iharob The sender is running on an ARM board, and the receiver is on my PC. A USB-Serial device is used since there's no serial port on my PC.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how to help you. It might be related to your specific setup, since the `write` function is sending the correct data and the code looks ok to me, so no idea what is going on. I wish i could help. I have worked with serial ports before, and never experienced this behaviour.

Comment: Does the transmit line have an appropriate pull-up (or pull-down) resistor to stop the line level from floating when it is not being driven?

Comment: Have you checked for framing and overrun errors?

Comment: There are two issues with the serial port setup: (1) the `struct termios attrs_` is not properly initialized; i.e. your program does not use **tcgetattr()**.  And hard assignments to these struct elements is considered bad practice. (2) VMIN = 0 and VTIME = 0 are considered a "bad idea" and almost always unnecessary.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237) and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).

Comment: your open statement is setting the no blocking parameter.  so even if nothing is sent, the receiver will still read characters.  I suggest using select() to wait for characters to be available, then reading the characters.  If you read the characters one char per select/read loop, then there will always be an actual character to read (until select() times out) on select timeout, skip the read() operation and exit the select/read loop

Comment: @SaltyEgg - *"The sender is running on an ARM board"* -- What ARM board? What SoC?  Freescale? Cirrus Logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check in your ARM board's documentation how the ARM's UART is hooked up and how it is configured in hardware and by your platform driver.

From what you describe, I would suppose that when opening the UART port on the ARM, the physical UART (i.e., the hardware peripheral module within the ARM or maybe an externally wired UART chip) is enabled or restored from some unknown idle state to the proper -12 Volt idle state of RS232. This transistion may be enough for your PC's UART to recognize a start bit and receive a bogus character.

You may want to check the serial line using an oscilloscope to see what happens when actually opening the port.

Comment: Good thought.  "open" library functions often configure pin multiplexing, while the serial port is "closed" the pin may be configured for use by some other peripheral (probably GPIO) other than the UART.  Of course, between microcontroller and USB-serial adapter one generally uses TTL serial.  Unlike RS-232, for TTL serial the idle state is positive voltage.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I have tested the code between two PCs, and the problem disappears.

Comment: This is why HW engineers hate programmers:  programmer's new code doesn't work, so he suspects the hardware to be faulty, even though code is full of flaws.  @BenVoigt  Please point out some code that has *"'open' library functions (that) often configure pin multiplexing"*.  Pin multiplexing is for design flexibility, and rarely used as dynamic reconfiguration.  The board would need to mirror the multiplexing of the SoC.

Answer (score 1):

the initial `\x0` is the indication that a parity or framing error occurred.
this error occurs because the termios fields are not being setup properly.
so the initial line high/low status and number of start/stop bits and parity
are not being setup properly.

you might read: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html 
which discusses each of the fields and their contents and meaning.

(The linked page is way too long to post here)

Comment: Please don't use code formatting (in this case, indentation) for content that is not code.

Comment: BTW if the stop bits or parity were misconfigured, it's unlikely that the following data would be correctly transferred.

Comment: But it is very likely that the 0x0 character is the (probably unconfigured) substitute character for any kind of reception error (PE, FE)